# right click option disabled for all objects in a access 2003 .MDB file

Tags: ms-access

The right click option has been disabled for all objects in an access 2003 .MDB file.
I would like to open the forms, reports etc in design view.
Which options should I check/Uncheck? Or is it due to User Permissions?

Please advise!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In start up options, you should find Allow Full Menus and Allow Built-in Toolbars check boxes, make sure they are allowed.